# jekyll build error unknown encoding name "chunked\r\n\r\n25"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I am trying something simple. Using Jekyll with Bundler. The first thing to do is create a new directory for your project and run  `bundle init`. This creates a new Bundler project (by creating an empty Gemfile).

```
mkdir my-jekyll-website
cd my-jekyll-website
bundle init
bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'  
bundle add jekyll
```

The last command gives me an issue.

```
C:\Users\***\Documents\LEARNING\web stuff\Jekyll\my-jekyll-website>bundle add jekyll
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching public_suffix 4.0.6
Installing public_suffix 4.0.6
Fetching addressable 2.7.0
Installing addressable 2.7.0
Using bundler 2.1.4
Fetching colorator 1.1.0
Installing colorator 1.1.0
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7 (x64-mingw32)
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 (x64-mingw32)
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Users/****/Documents/LEARNING/web
stuff/Jekyll/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20200925-7100-x9bvnr.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Users/***/Documents/LEARNING/web
stuff/Jekyll/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Users/***/Documents/LEARNING/web
stuff/Jekyll/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
generating ruby_http_parser-x64-mingw32.def
compiling ruby_http_parser.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe: error:
stuff/Jekyll/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser:
No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:244: ruby_http_parser.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/***/Documents/LEARNING/web
stuff/Jekyll/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0
for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/***/Documents/LEARNING/web
stuff/Jekyll/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing http_parser.rb (0.6.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install http_parser.rb -v '0.6.0' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
    em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
      http_parser.rb
```

What am I missing? Why is this happening?

When I run,
`gem install http_parser.rb -v '0.6.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

I get the following output,

```
http://rubygems.org' Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW... 
Building native extensions. This could take a while... 
Successfully installed http_parser.rb-0.6.0 
Parsing documentation for http_parser.rb-0.6.0 unknown encoding name "chunked\r\n\r\n25" for ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/tools/parse_tests.rb, 
skipping 
Done installing documentation for http_parser.rb after 1 seconds 
1 gem installed
```

Any pointers that will help me out of this?

I am running this on a Windows 10 laptop.
The code editor is VS Code and the Jekyll version is 4.1.1.

Comment: So for now I've tried skipping the 4th command from top (bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle') and it seems to work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on windows 10. In my case, the issue seemed to be caused by my Windows path including a folder with a space in its name and I see that you were in the same position ("web stuff"). Note the wording of the error - it only includes the section of the path following the space. In my case, moving the installation to a different folder without a space in the name fixed the problem.

```
compiling ruby_http_parser.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe: error:
stuff/Jekyll/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser:
No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:244: ruby_http_parser.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I guess that the compilation stage has failed to quote the name of the file to compile. I'm not a Ruby or Jekyll developer and don't know where to log that issue.